# What does "red" mean in the context of a crime scene?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I [read](https://www.kktv.com/2021/05/10/graphic-dispatch-transcript-from-colorado-springs-birthday-party-shooting/):

> AMR has sent six ambulances. Three are on scene and three are still en route. Updated triage. We have that one critical that’s already been transported and six black. Update: Total of seven. Six black. One **red** that has been transported.

What does "red" mean in the context of a crime scene? Covered with blood? Face turned red? Something else?

Comment: I think some more context and text would be helpful, but I think the Triage answer is right. As a native speaker I wouldn't have thought about this- it's professional jargon, and should get some more context in the passage.

Comment: @VWFeature thanks I extended the quote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Triage colours](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triage_tag)

The colour black is used to indicate dead, red for life threatening injuries

Comment: I should add that this would be pretty impenetrable for even an average English speaker - I thought it was card suits at first

Comment: Note that 'black' doesn't necessarily mean 'dead now', but does mean 'beyond help'. Depending on just how overloaded a situation is those people may still receive something for pain but resources are still going to be concentrated on people that are actually capable of being saved.

Comment: The 'Updated triage.' makes the context clear. Good call!